# ntop won't install properly after reinstall (Ubuntu 11.04)

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, apt-get

I installed ntop (with all its dependencies) like this:

```
sudo apt-get install ntop
```

After that I decided to remove it by issuing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove ntop
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /etc/ntop && sudo rm -rf /etc/init.d/ntop
```

After that I decided to install it again by issuing:

```
sudo apt-get install ntop
```

And the `/etc/init.d/ntop` file did not get created this time! Also, the `/etc/ntop/` directory is empty. I also noticed that during the second install the installer did not ask me for username/password, or an interface list to monitor.

Is there some indication on the system that this package has been installed before and how do I clean my system of all mention of this package (so that it can be completely reinstalled)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're certain it's been purged, try this (note the 'y' switch):

```
sudo apt-get install ntop -y
```

Then set it up with:

```
sudo ntop --set-admin-password
sudo ntop -u ntop -d
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get --purge remove ntop && sudo apt-get autoremove` along with the suggested ones by you did the trick. Also, it reinstalled the `/etc/init.d/ntop script` ^^.